# Generate path from 2 coordinates

Tags: php, jquery

This is kind of hard to explain...

I have an image (campus map), for example I have coordinates of A and B relative to the image, I need to generate a path from A to B using the roads in the map, kinda like google directions but not that complex. I created a table of locations and their coordinates in the database like this:

```
id | coord_x | coord_y | location
1  | 45      | 150     | Library
2  | 61      | 80      | Cafeteria
```

I'm confused in the road part, I mean I can create a straight line from A to B but I need to use the road as path (like google directions). I don't know how I will save the roads in the database and how I will calculate the path, need help pls...

Comment: does the campus appear on google maps (or any other public online mapping service)? you'd probably save a lot of time by just plugging into their API to plot routes.

Comment: I wish I could do that, but it's an intranet project only connected to local network, even if it's not, google wouldn't know where cafeteria is located, or where dean's office is and etc...

Comment: it would if you tagged them...much of the location data on Maps is added by regular users. So there's no outbound HTTP access to the web from your campus intranet? Unusual, but I guess some networks are still very locked down. Sorry I have no better solution - what you're attempting is potentially very complex. Will this just be a static set of routes, or can it be added to arbitrarily? If it's just static you could just plot the route as a series of "waypoint" co-ordinates and then draw lines between each point on the route. Not as sophisticated as defining roads etc but it would do a job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to set waypoints and connect them in a way it is possible to walk along the connections.
If you are allowed to use any datastore you want I would go for a graph database and build upon the following example: https://neo4j.com/blog/finding-the-shortest-path-through-the-park/